# Создание словаря из текста & python

Tags: python, строки, dict

Во допустим у нас есть вот такая **строка**

`' {"1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three"} '`скаду ещё раз, это не словарь, а строка.
Мне нужно из этой строки создать словарь, то есть

```
s = ' {"1": "one", "2":"two"} '
print(f"STRING: {s}) #str
print(f"DICT: {s.функция}) #dict
>>>STRING: {"1": "one", "2":"two"} 
>>>DICT: {"1": "one", "2":"two"}
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте модуль `json`:

```python
import json

s = ' {"1": "one", "2":"two"} '
print(f"STRING: {s}") #str
print(f"DICT: {json.loads(s)}") #dict
```

Функция `json.loads` как раз делает то, что Вам нужно. Однако будьте внимательны: кавычки **внутри** строки обязательно должны быть двойными. То есть, если бы строка была такая `s = " {'1': 'one', '2':'two'} "`, это бы не сработало.

Либо, как в комментарии посоветовал [@MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo), воспользуйтесь ответом из [данного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/988228/11790859). То есть, используйте модуль `ast`:

```python
import ast

s = ' {"1": "one", "2":"two"} '
print(f"STRING: {s}") #str
print(f"DICT: {ast.literal_eval(s)}") #dict
```

В данном случае кавычки уже значения не имеют.

UPD: По объективным причинам (читайте комментарии к ответу) второй вариант более предпочтителен.

Comment: Ну, на самом деле, разница не только в кавычках. Метод `json.loads` пытается интерпретировать строку как последовательность **json** литералов (т.е. те же двойные кавычки, `true`, а не `True`, `null`, а не `None`). Модуль `ast` же интерпретирует строку как последовательность **Python** литералов (т.е. кавычки уже неважны, не съестся литерал `true`, но съестся `True` и тд).

Answer (score -1):

есть втроенный метод eval

`s = ' {"1": "one", "2":"two"} '`

`s_to_dict = eval(s)`

`print(type(s_to_dict))  #<class 'dict'>`

Comment: Лучше пользоваться теми методами, которые описаны в одобренном ответе. `eval` - небезопасный метод.